# Laravel route with '%' special char

Tags: php, laravel

I have a route which is:

```
Route::get('/busca-de-produtos/{produto?}', ['as' => 'busca-de-produto', 'uses' => 'ProdutoController@buscaProdutos'])->where('produto', '(.*)');
```

That works for almost everything, but if I search for: 'Some Product 2% more text' it doesn't work.

I tried changing to:

```
Route::get('/busca-de-produtos/{produto?}', ['as' => 'busca-de-produto', 'uses' => 'ProdutoController@buscaProdutos'])->where('produto', '((?s).*)');
```

But it didn't work as well. Is there anyway I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not properly encoding the URL when doing the search.
Your URL should look like this `/busca-de-produtos/Some%20Product%202%25%20more%20text`

Also, if you are accepting `.*` for produto, I think you can safely drop the `->where()` filter entirely.

Comment: No, the name of the product has the '%' on it and when I search the database I need to search including this char. It's not a matter of encoding URL.

Comment: Could you post the error you are getting and also some code sample of how you're doing the search?

Comment: It's a 400 error, it doesn't hit the controller. That's my problem. The route needs to accept '%' in order to hit the controller.

Comment: I see, have you tried removing the `->where()` filter from your route, and opening the URL I wrote in my answer in your web browser? There's no reason for Laravel not to accept the % character as long as it's properly encoded.

Comment: I wanted the URL to be friendly, and not having it encoded. Otherwise is not very legible.If I url encode it, It works, but I wanted to accept special char in the route.

Comment: That's the way HTTP works, not much you can do to make the search URL friendlier if it contains special characters, unfortunately.

Comment: I am sure there's a way because with the where I put in the route, I can search for example for:"Product 150mg/200" and It works as a string. The only problem is the %

Comment: % is an escape char, so that's why it won't work with it. Also, having spaces in your URL isn't very good practice either, let's say someone copy pastes the link and it looks like this "example.com/some words here" but all software will only highlight & make clickable up until the first space - "example.com/some"